# Error resolving dependency, "E: Unable to locate package docbook2x-man"

Tags: package-management

Good day,

I am trying to install the above mentioned package but
updating the 
package database or installing via package
does not seem to work.

I reinstalled docbook2x and docbook-to-man.

But upon calling an installation script, which uses docbook2x for
 
documentation purposes (I presume) I'm stuck with the message.

```
E: Unable to locate package docbook2x-man
```

Best regards,
hph

Comment: Are you following some guide? Where do you see recommendation on installation of `docbook2x-man` package? What do you plan to achieve by its installation?

Comment: It seems to be an essential part of an installation script, where
the script runs
"sudo apt -y install docbook2x-man" 
and
"sudo apt -y install docbook2x-to-man" 

Locating the docboo2x-man package works, is correctly placed in /usr/bin/docbook2x-man
What's missing is the docbook2x-to-man package.

Comment: It seems that you need to change installation script. I can find only [docbook2x](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=docbook2x) package.